# Getcomponent<thisScript>() vs this

Tags: unity, c#

I am referencing singleton script's object from another script and I wonder what is difference between this two, or if even work the second one properly?

```
GameManager.Instance.selectedBuildSite = GetComponent<BuildSite>();
```

VS

```
GameManager.Instance.selectedBuildSite = this;
```

The code is written inside BuildSite class which inherits monobehaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is never a reason to search for a reference to a component if you already have a reference to the component you want to use.

`this` inside a non-static class method refers to the instance of the class currently running that method. So here, `this` is the specific `BuildSite` component that's running this method.

`GetComponent<BuildSite>()` will search all the components attached to `this.gameObject` until it finds one that is a `BuildSite` and return that. That search can be costly, so we don't want to pay that cost unnecessarily.

The only time when that might give a different result than `this` when run from inside your `BuildSite` script is if you have two `BuildSite` components attached to your object - which would probably be an error for your case, or at the very least, you'd want to enforce some logic about which one should be chosen, rather than leaving it up to the whims of which one the search finds first.

**tl;dr:** if `this` is what you want to reference, just say `this`.